# Why signal update is not reflected in the UI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

So I have the following code in SolidJS.

I am using `createSignal` and I want to render certain views when the values in `options` changes.

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, Show, Index } from "solid-js";

const options = [
        {
            title: "ReactJs",
            subtitle: "A front-end framework for building views on the web",
            selected: false
        },
        {
            title: "SolidJS",
            subtitle: "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.",
            selected: false
        },
        {
            title: "MumboJumboJS",
            subtitle: "null",
            selected: false
        }
    ]


export default function CheckboxArea(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = createSignal(props.options);
    console.log(options())

    function onClickListener(index: number) {
        console.log("Click")
        const op = options()
        op[index].selected = true
        setOptions(op)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <Index each={options()}>{(each_option, index) =>
                <div onClick={() => onClickListener(index)}>
                    <Show when={options()[index].selected}>
                        <div>{each_option().title}</div>
                    </Show>
                    <Show when={!options()[index].selected}>
                        <div>{each_option().subtitle}</div>
                    </Show>
                </div>
            }
            </Index>
        </div>
    )
}

render(() => <CheckboxArea options={options}/>, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Of course click events register and `options()` updates but the views do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to mutate an existing value and setting it back as the new value. However signals run equality checks internally, since you are passing the same value, because arrays are objects and objects are compared by reference, signal's value is never updated.

There are several solutions, most basic one is create a new array with updated values and set it as the new value:

```
function onClickListener(index: number) {
  setOptions([...updatedList]);
}
```

Alternatively you can set equals to false on the signal, so to force an update even if the value is same.

```
createSignal(props.options, { equals: false });
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, what are the other ways of solving this problem?

Comment: Related is [`createStore`](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createstore), but i'm not sure if it works with arrays

Comment: Solid store uses a signal internally, signal is wrapped with a proxy to provide a controlled access. So, same rules applies whether you use a signal or a store. Since only array and objects can use the proxy API, you can only use these two in a store.